# word 2013 header numbering in disorder - heal by copy/paste

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2013, microsoft-word-2016

Using office words since a few decades, I miss robustness in hierarchical header numbering since 2010. Every now an then, but more than expected,  the hierarchical header numbering of headers gets into disorder and it is a real pain to repair it. Since Office 2010 the header number seems to be  caused by a complex interaction of header levels and attached numbering formats.

I'm not looking for a 1:1 repair work instruction for illfitted header level numberings on that complex level.

I have a document template with correct and sound numbering of header levels.

What I expect is

1. Opening a new file
2. Copy/paste the content of the illfited file into the new file.
3. After pasting, the content should correctly align and number accourding to the sound template definitions in the receiving file based on a sound template.

What I get is:
By pasting, *the problem is pasted into the receiving file*, too.

Before word 2010, pasting into a new file based on a robust template worked well for repairing ill formats. How can I realize this with Office 2013-2019?

By the way:
As a frequently paste text from third-party sources, inclusive web pages, pasting text seems to be to source of **destructive header numbering desease** in office word.

What I expect is a fitting of the pasted text to the nearest template, without importing, and thus overriding template specific deviations.

Are there any options to taylor this?

Comment: What paste options are you using?

Comment: Source-Doc CTRL-A, CNTRL-C, Destination-Doc: CTRL-V. My Copy/Paste Default Option setup: Pasting beween documents when style definitions conflict: Use destination styles (default).

Comment: Source and destination style are "Ueberschrift 2; gegliedert 2". In destination the style works well for any new inserted header 2 (=Ueberschrift 2"), inclusive correct numbering systematics. Included "header 2" keeps disorder in its numbering systematics.

Comment: I can suggest a number of things to try @olippuner, but I don't have an answer.   I often encounter similar issues when dealing with documents that are revised and returned to me.  If you are using only the Headers to apply formatting, try using the Format Painter to copy the format from your destination Header 2 to an added Header 2.  If this works, you can manually do the same to all the included Headers or perhaps use Find and Replace to update them all at once if the document is long.

Comment: If you're using a Multi Level list with the headers incorporated in your destination document, you can reapply the list to the entire document.  This usually works for me.  I have had cases where I simply couldn't isolate the issue and I have had to strip all formatting and reapply the formatting from scratch.  Of course this a terrible option as it means working paragraph by paragraph to define the outline.  Please let us know if any of this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks KnotWright. I can't track this problem in the moment, but it's a long-term issue [I have word 2019 now, the problem exists since 2010). I will come back on this.